# HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden with Debug of ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, http-error, iis-manager

I'm trying to start ASP.NET Web Application

but I got this error with debug:

```
HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list
the contents of this directory.

Module
   DirectoryListingModule
Notification
   ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler
   StaticFile
Error Code
   0x00000000
```

Not sure if it exactly what I have to do, but as it shown, I must follow this [instruction](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/942062/-http-error-403.14---forbidden-error-when-you-open-an-iis-7.0-webpage) but when I'm trying to open [IIS Manager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763170.aspx) on Windows 10, it says that the Windows cannot find 'inetmgr'.or 'inetmgr.exe'

So not sure what I have to do to figure out with this error.

Comment: You may have described two separate issues. Double check:  Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off and see if Internet Information Services is installed.  It would be weird if it wasn't.  Also try iisreset from command prompt.  It should really be able to find inetmgr.

Comment: @secretwep yes it is installed IIS Express Application Capability Database for x64 and x86. it is first time I have deal with web application so maybe I need configure Microsoft azure web app settings and sing up for subscription?

Comment: I believe that inetmgr only applies to IIS, not IIS Express.  At least in Win7, IIS Express has no user interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it doesn't seem like you have the full IIS installed, try adding this into your web.config that lies within the directory you want to browse:

```
<system.webServer>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

...at least so you can get past this problem.  If you're doing this for debugging, fine, but you have to seriously consider whether this is really what you want to allow on a production server.

Comment: Hello, so now I see my localhost - / with <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>